# How to find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of $(x^{3}+x^{4}+\cdots )^{3}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in the expansion of $(x^{3}+x^{4}+\cdots )^{3}$?

Here is what i started,
$(x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}\cdots )^{3}= x^{3}(1+x+x^{2}+ \cdots )^{3} = x^{9}(1+x+x^{2})^{3} = x^{9}(\frac{1}{1-x})^{3} =  x^{9}(1-x)^{-3}$

I cannot finish it and I'm confused with this problem. Please help me get with this.

Thank you for any help anent this problem.

Comment: There are 3 ways of having $x^3 \times x^3 \times x^{14}$. 
There are $6$ ways of having $x^3 \times x^4 \times x^{13}$.  Draw up a precise list of the number of ways that you can have $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 20$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are each positive integers $\geq 3.$  For each way that involves two numbers the same, multiply by $(3)$.  For each way that involves three numbers the same, multiply by $(6)$.  Note that [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) is no good here, because you must distinguish those solutions with either 2 or 3 distinct numbers.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to creatively consider Stars and Bars, distinguishing between those solutions with two identical numbers, and those solutions with 3 distinct numbers.  However, I question whether it is worth the trouble, in this instance.

Comment: Can you write the generating function $x^3 + x^4 + \ldots$ in a closed form?

Comment: @TheoBendit Good comment.  It is important for the OP (i.e. the original poster) to realize that my previous comments came from someone totally ignorant of generating functions).

Comment: If you're going to count them, I'd recommend factoring out $x^9(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^3$ and focus on finding the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^3$

Comment: For the next step, try computing $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{1}{1 - x}$. See if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

@Theo Bendit has pretty much given you the answer in the comments. But, alternatively, perhaps it would be helpful for you to note that, for any real $n$, the following generalisation of the binomial theorem holds, known as Newton's series:
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!} x^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} x^3+...\infty$$
Thus, substituting $x\to -x$ and $n=-3$ would allow you to calculate the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in $(1-x)^{-3}$.